# Is it possible to set path mappings with wildcards in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to configured wildcard path mapping in Azure portal?
I don't want to specify all virtual paths that my frontend is using. `/*` you see on screen below doesn't work.

[image: Path mappings in Azure Portal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set wildcard path mapping in the web app, even if you use `/*`, the `*` will be recognized as a normal string.